# System.Windows.Controls.RadioButton problems

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wpf-controls

I'm trying to test whether a radio button is checked, and I keep getting the error that Checked and isChecked are not valid methods for that `RadioButton` class.  I'm using C# and Visual Studio 2010.

Example

```
if (radioButton4.Checked) maxTotal = 660;
```

This error seems specific to the `System.Windows.Controls.RadioButton` class.  If I create a `System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton` from within the code, I don't get the errors.  The problem is that the `RadioButton` that I drag onto the stage (I come from as3) from the WPF Controls Toolbox is of the `System.Windows.Controls` variety.

I need to figure out how to add the `System.Windows.Forms` variety of RadioButton to my toolbox, or figure out why the Checked property is not valid with the Controls version.  It doesn't make sense.  Everywhere I've looked says it should work.

I created the app as a WPF Application.  I'm using one of the Forms controls to do something that I think couldn't be done without it.  And from what I understand, the Forms components are meant to be used with a Windows Forms Application.  So my problem might have something to do with that, but I don't know.

Comment: For WPF try using IsChecked? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked.aspx

Answer (score 2):

To check if a WPF toggle button is checked use the `IsChecked` property. 
System.Windows.Controls.RadioButton is a descendant class of the ToggleButton.

You should not mix WPF and Windows Forms controls if it is not absolutely neccessary.